# Change array index of mysql query result set

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

This is mymysql table

```
id  name   ssn    phone       email**  
1   Asok   5466   9865893265  asok@gmail.com  
2   Sokan  7856   9562358965  sakan@gmail.com
......  
.....
```

when I am using select query, i will get result as:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Asok [sin] => 5466 [phone] => 9865893265 [email] => asok@gmail.com )  [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Sokan [sin] => 7856 [phone] => 9562358965 [email] => sakan@gmail.com ) ...)`
```

I need to get this result as

```
Array ( [5466] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Asok [sin] => 5466 [phone] => 9865893265 [email] => asok@gmail.com )  
[7856] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Sokan [sin] => 7856 [phone] => 9562358965 [email] => sakan@gmail.com ) ...)
```

using  sql query

Here the index 5466 and 7856 are the field 'ssn' (this is a unique no to that person)

Comment: You can use foreach loop to create the new array with sin as key

Comment: @chandresh_cool - Is it possible to get it using query itself ?

Comment: @user2609417 Using query is not possible.

Comment: Not possible using sql

Answer (score 1):

Do you want like this?

SQL column name `ssn`, result array index `sin`. I wrote as `sin`

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($results as $row)
{
   $newArray[$row['sin']] = $row;
}
```

Comment: I know this.  But i need this using query itself

Answer (score 0):

Look https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/429

this link same is being discussed

```
functions map_array($key_field, $value_field) and map($key_field, $value_field)
that return a map (dictionary) from the result set
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mySQL Index Hint Syntax
[index hint syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html)